Wrap all elements between two elements regardless of what they are without having to add classes
I'm trying to wrap all of the elements between two headings regardless of what they are without having to add classes. Example:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".axxs-accordion > :header").addClass("h-trigger static").next().wrap("<div class='section collapsed'></div>");
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="axxs-accordion">
  <h2>Section with a Paragraph</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <p>Here is some text content</p>
  <!-- to here -->
  <h2>Section with a Div and Mixed Content</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Here is some content with text and a link.</p>
  <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Test link</a></p>
  <!-- to here -->
  <h2>Section with a List</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- to here -->
</div>



Obviously it works in the first and third sections, because there is only one element after the H2. But how do I wrap the group of elements in the second section? I've seen other posts about nextUntil, but those all of those examples had classes to work off of.

Actually, you do not need the class on h2 element:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.axxs-accordion h2').each(function() {
    var $h2 = $(this);
    var $content = $h2.nextUntil('h2');
    $content.wrapAll('<div class="section-content"></div>');
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="axxs-accordion">
  <h2>Section with a Paragraph</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <p>Here is some text content</p>
  <!-- to here -->

  <h2>Section with a Div and Mixed Content</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Here is some content with text and a link.</p>
  <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Test link</a></p>
  <!-- to here -->

  <h2>Section with a List</h2>
  <!-- wrap here -->
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- to here -->
</div>




This doesn't quite work. It needs to work regardless of whether the trigger element is an H1, H2, H3, H4, etc., not just an H2. Guess I should have been more specific about that.
